# Number from strong and multiply with a value

Tags: java

Given a string `123456` and 3 numbers `2,4,6`. How can I multiply the string 1 with the first number and 2 with the 2 second number and 3 with the third number and this continue. No matter how long this strings get, it will multiply 2,4,6 for each number

### Example

1***2** 2***4** 3***6** 4***2** 5***4** 6***6**

### Code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String id = "123456";

        int n1 = 2;
        int n2 = 4;
        int n3 = 6;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will print out the result of product of each number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String id = "123456";
    int[] n={1,2,3};
    int output=0;
    for(int i=0; i<id.length(); i++){
        int j = i % 3;
        int no = Integer.parseInt(id.substring(i, i+1));
        output = no*n[j];
        System.out.println(no + "*" + n[j] + "=" + output);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
1*1=1
2*2=4
3*3=9
4*1=4
5*2=10
6*3=18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String id = "123456";

int[] arr={2,4,6};
for(int x=0;x<id.length();x++){
    char c=id.charAt(x);
    if(Character.isDigit(c)){
        int j=x%3;
        int w=(int)c;
        if(w<65){
        int a1=(w-48)*arr[j];
        System.out.print(a1+" ");
        }
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2 8 18 8 20 36
```

Answer (score -1):

Use nested for loop like below.

```
int[] n={1,2,3};
int output=0;
for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n.length;i++){
   output=Integer.parseInt(id[i])*n[j];
     ......
  }
}
```

Note: please take care of additional code part

Comment: it gives output as 1 2 3 4 5 6 , but he wants ans like 1 4 9 4 10 18